# How to center div and text align left?

Tags: css

I have this demo http://jsfiddle.net/CGP87/2601/ but i dont know how to center this div and inside it to put this text align left. Any suggestion?

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div class="row-left">
        <h2>BAVARIA 31</h2>
        <h4>(ID : 1021)</h4>
        <div class="stars-rating">
           <fieldset class="rating">
            <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
         </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ PraveenKumar how this is duplicate?

Comment: What exactly do you want to center?

Comment: i want to center row-left but inside to be text-align:left

Comment: Using bootstrap would be one possible solution: http://www.bootply.com/0kV1kUIIAi

Comment: but text inside is not text-align:left

Comment: Which text should be left and which text should be centered?

Comment: text inside row-left need to be centered but text-align:left

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/CGP87/2602/) is your solution, but still this is duplicate.

Comment: @DevidasKadam only stars are centered in your solution

Comment: so what ? still you are not able to center other data ?

Comment: im not able to center other data to be text-align:left :(